# Expected "," on inline css styling

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a dumb styling compile error.. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax...
Here is my code...

```html
<TouchableOpacity style={{marginRight:40}} onPress={() => this.handleBlueSelection}>
    <View style={this.state.blue_selected ? {styles.team_selected} : {null}}>
        <Image style={{height:30, width:30}} source={require('../../assets/images/blue.png')} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the error:

```
TransformError SyntaxError: C:\edit_profile.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (294:54)
```

I know is a dumb question but cannot find the correct syntax..

Thanks

Comment: So have a look @ line 294, char 54 then (C:\edit_profile.js)

Comment: Which line is line 294?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder don't know, but the error message says so..

Comment: @Reto - That was a question for the OP, not for you. :-)

Comment: that line :
<View style={this.state.blue_selected ? {styles.team_selected} : {null}} >

Answer (score 3):

```
<View style={this.state.blue_selected ? {styles.team_selected} : {null}} >
```

`styles.team_selected` and `null` don't need braces around them.  The reason the other style requires them is because you need to pass an object of styles (the first pair is to denote js, the second pair constructs the style object).

Comment: this compiles but do not work. Either blue_selected is true or false always is null... styles.team_selected is never active

Comment: Sounds like a completely different question altogether.  But maybe take a look at this part here `onPress={()=> this.handleBlueSelection}`.  You're not actually calling `handleBlueSelection` on press, you're just returning a reference to it.